# Finding the next memory variable for multinested array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

So I have a multi-nested array  (pointers use 32-bits)

the application has variable defined as

char magicball[8][8][8]

(gbp) p  &magic&ball

if base address of char *[8][8][8] is 0xffffd448 what is address of magicball[3][2]

I used the formula Address = Base address + N(i*C + k)

= base address + 4(3*8+2)

= base address + 104(dec)

= base address + 68(hex).

correct answer is base address + 208(dec)  (why is it 208 instead of 104)
source: http://www.bruintestbank.com/computer-science/cs-33-1/
2nd page

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 4, there's nothing here that's 4 bytes in size - it's `char`s all the way down.

Comment: pointer uses 32 bits so 4 bytes

Comment: please check link for clarificiation, i m off by factor of two dont know how

Comment: There are no pointers here, the array consists of 8*8*8 = 512 1-byte characters.

Comment: What exactly is a multinested array?

Answer (score 0):

The address of the `magicball[3][2]` should be at offset `(2*8)+(3*64)`, which is `208`.

If we think of your array as being labelled by dimensions x, y, z, then each step in the z direction moves you by `sizeof(char)` (i.e. 1) bytes. Each step in the y direction moves you by the number of elements in the z direction (i.e. 8). Each step in the x direction moves you by the total number of elements in each y/z plane (i.e. 8*8*sizeof(char)) bytes. Putting all that together gives a byte offset of 208 for the slice at `x=3`, `y=2`.

Comment: would it different  if it was 32 bit machine or 64 bit machine? Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't be - the memory alignment of an 8-bit quantity should always be a single byte, and is probably guaranteed by the C standard. To be sure, you might want to include sizeof(char) in your calculations.

Comment: sorry one more question for future reference. if it was int instead of char, i multiple by the offset by 4 right? so offset becomes 832. Can you please confirm

Comment: Yes, if you multiply by `sizeof(int)` you should indeed get 832. Using `sizeof` explicitly in your code, rather than just `4`, will make your intention clearer. You might even consider using `sizeof(magicball[0][0][0])`, which would allow you to change the declaration of your magicball array without needing to also change the computation of your offset.

Answer (score 0):

`char magicball[8][8][8]` takes up 8*8*8*sizeof(char) = 512 bytes of contiguous memory.

`magicball[x][y][z]` references the element offset by x*64+y*8+z bytes from the start address.

`magicball[3][2]` is a pointer to `magicball[3][2][0]`. Therefore it is offset 3*64+2*8+0 = 208 bytes from the start address.

Comment: would it matter if it was 32 bit machine or 64 bit machine?

Comment: No. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.